# Flex box of two charts is overflowing screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, chakra-ui

I have a two charts on my page. Together, they take up the entire screen height through `Flex` (a css flexbox). The first chart is collapsible via an `Accordion`.

How we can make the first chart fill up 30% of the screen height, and the second chart fill up the remaining ~70%?

I was able to do this successfully when these two charts are the *only* things on the page:

[image]

```
// This works well.
<Flex direction="column" height="100vh">
  <Accordion allowToggle>
    <AccordionItem>
      <h2>
        <AccordionButton
          h={0}
          borderRadius="md"
          borderWidth="0px"
          _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
        >
          <Box
            textAlign="left"
            h={3}
            _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
          ></Box>
          <AccordionIcon />
        </AccordionButton>
      </h2>
      <AccordionPanel p="0">
        <Box height="30vh">
          <ThreeDataPoint />
        </Box>
      </AccordionPanel>
    </AccordionItem>
  </Accordion>
  <Box flex="1">
    <ThreeDataPoint />
  </Box>
</Flex>
```

However, if I combine a row and column flex box together, it doesn't work. The second chart overflows the screen's height.

[Here's the CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-breeze-qnvll?file=/src/index.tsx)

And here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: maybe using the chakra `sx` to add a "first-child"/"nth-child" selector would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code, trying to achieve a somewhat satisfying result, which keeps both charts in that `100vh` max height and avoids scrolling.

The height of the second chart will be automatic, filling as much space as available depending on whether or not the first one is collapsed.

Down here is some styling I added in your styles.css file (right under your `.test` class):

```
.flex-wrapper {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content auto;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion-box-container {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
  gap: 15px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.accordion-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: auto;
}

.accordion-button {
  width: min-content !important;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.graph-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.graph-wrapper div {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Meanwhile, I removed some of the bootstrap classes from your jsx in `index.tsx` and added the css classes above to the appropriate components:

```
render(
  <ChakraProvider>
    <>
      <Flex direction="column" height="100vh" className="flex-wrapper">
        <div>123456789010</div>
        <Flex>
          <Box className="accordion-box-container">
            <Accordion className="accordion-wrapper" allowToggle>
              <AccordionItem>
                <h2 className="accordion-title">
                  <AccordionButton
                    className="accordion-button"
                    borderRadius="md"
                    borderWidth="0px"
                    _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
                  >
                    <Box
                      textAlign="left"
                      h={3}
                      _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
                    ></Box>
                    <AccordionIcon />
                  </AccordionButton>
                </h2>
                <AccordionPanel p="0">
                  <Box height="30vh">
                    <ThreeDataPoint />
                  </Box>
                </AccordionPanel>
              </AccordionItem>
            </Accordion>
            <div className="graph-wrapper">
              <ThreeDataPoint />
            </div>
          </Box>
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </>
  </ChakraProvider>,
  rootElement
);
```

Finally, I had to remove your restriction for size in `BasicLineSeries.tsx` which would enforce the min height to both charts making it impossible to adjust their height after rendering (only changed the export statement):

```
export default withSize()(
  withDeviceRatio()(BasicLineSeries)
);
```

Please try to test this out on your own and let me know if this is somewhat satisfying to your requirements. If something else is needed, comment it and I'll do my best to adjust my solution accordingly.

[image: preview1]
[image: preview2]

Comment: Hi Kevin. I need the number 123456789010 to be on the left-hand-side of the Accordion. They're supposed to be separate columns. In my application, "123456789010" is actually another component.  I just put some simple text there as a placeholder for this example. That's why I used the row flex-box in my example. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to modify your solution to account for this?

Comment: @ABC Yes, I'll have a look at it, I just misunderstood your intentions. :)
Should both charts be in the same column, separated from the text?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I should've made it clearer in the OP.

Comment: @ABC Done with the edits, please check out the previews and tell me if it's what you were expecting.

Comment: Yer a wizard, Harry!

Comment: @ABC Glad to have been of help, please mark this as the solution to your question if this works out for you.

Comment: I realize there's a problem with this solution. Have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fermat-bugv1?file=/src/index.tsx, or here: https://bugv1.csb.app/. To replicate the issue: (1) Make sure your browser window is small (doesn't take up your whole monitor). (2) Make sure the accordion is expanded, (3) Maximize the browser to fill your screen. (4) Then collapse the accordion. --- The result will be whitespace at the bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235467/discussion-between-kevin-haxhi-and-abc).

Answer (score 1):

Charts height is calculated when page renders, so after toggling top chart bottom chart height won't be recalculated. You need to do workaround to trigger event for recalculating height of the second chart. You can use `onChange` event for `<Accordion>` to toggle state and wrap your second chart into `<Box>` with height `100vh` or `70vh` based on the state change.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import BasicLineSeries from "./BasicLineSeries";
import {
  Box,
  Accordion,
  AccordionButton,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionIcon,
  AccordionPanel,
  Flex,
  Text
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

const ThreeDataPoint = () => (
  <BasicLineSeries
    data={[
      {
        close: 120,
        open: 120,
        high: 140,
        low: 100,
        date: new Date(2020, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0, 0),
        volume: 1_000_000
      },
      {
        close: 140,
        open: 120,
        high: 150,
        low: 100,
        date: new Date(2020, 7, 8, 10, 1, 0, 0),
        volume: 1_000_000
      },
      {
        close: 120,
        open: 120,
        high: 140,
        low: 100,
        date: new Date(2020, 7, 8, 10, 2, 0, 0),
        volume: 1_000_000
      }
    ]}
  />
);

const Test = () => {
  const [expended, onExpend] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <>
        <Flex direction="column" height="100vh">
          <Flex flex="1" direction="row">
            <div>123456789010</div>
            <Flex flex="1" direction="column">
              <Accordion
                allowToggle
                onChange={(e) => {
                  if (e === 0) {
                    onExpend(true);
                  } else {
                    onExpend(false);
                  }
                }}
              >
                <AccordionItem>
                  <h2>
                    <AccordionButton
                      h={0}
                      borderRadius="md"
                      borderWidth="0px"
                      _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
                    >
                      <Box
                        textAlign="left"
                        h={3}
                        _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
                      ></Box>
                      <AccordionIcon />
                    </AccordionButton>
                  </h2>
                  <AccordionPanel p="0">
                    <Box height="30vh">
                      <ThreeDataPoint />
                    </Box>
                  </AccordionPanel>
                </AccordionItem>
              </Accordion>
              <Box flex={expended ? 2 : 3}>
                <ThreeDataPoint />
              </Box>
            </Flex>
          </Flex>
        </Flex>
      </>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Test />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Almost but not quite. The bottom of the second chart (the x-axis) is being chopped off. 

30vh + 70vh is too big because it doesn't account for any stuff above both charts (in this case, the accordion drop-down menu)

Comment: That was quick example how you can resolve your problem. I am sure you will have some header/footer on your page, so you should account for that as well

Comment: But even in the absence of a header & footer, the problem isn't resolved. The solution you're proposing causes a page overflow due to the Accordion itself

Comment: That's odd, it's not working for me. The expanded accordion is still overflowing. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-meadow-ipx0b?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome :-)

Comment: I don't see any issues. I am on Version 92.0.4515.107 of Google Chrome and using Mac

Comment: I'm getting screen overflow on both Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome when viewing your solution via ipx0b.csb.app (which is generated by the above codesandbox). Are you sure that you're expanding the accordion such that both charts are visible simultaneously, when you are testing it out? For me, your solution seems to work only when the accordion is not expanded and only 1 chart is visible. Screenshot - https://ibb.co/hgwwHrC

Comment: It looks like you have a small screen, and charts cannot fit. In `BasicLineSeries` you specified min height is `600`